Why am I receiving an invalid PHP type error?
I am trying to execute a PHP command async form original request.
While trying this I found php-enqueue for Symfony (6.4):

https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev
https://php-enqueue.github.io/bundle/quick_tour/
Async Command: https://php-enqueue.github.io/bundle/async_commands/

My Symfony Database is a SQL Server.
I have installed the enqueue modules with composer. This worked fine.
The table enqueue got created.
When I now try to save a command to the Queue, I get an error:
$cmd = new RunCommand('debug:container', ['--tag=form.type']);
$producer->sendCommand(Commands::RUN_COMMAND, $cmd);

Error:

[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException (-16)]
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE [IMSSP, -16]: An invalid PHP type for parameter 1 was specified

While debugging I found out that parameter 1 is the id field of the database.
The Id is set at https://github.com/php-enqueue/dbal/blob/2375961434e2a69b8710875f1c4e56f01b348a47/DbalProducer.php#L69  with Uuid:uuid4() function. 'id' => Uuid::uuid4(),
It returns an object for id:
Array
(
    [id] => Ramsey\Uuid\Lazy\LazyUuidFromString Object
        (
            [unwrapped:Ramsey\Uuid\Lazy\LazyUuidFromString:private] => 
            [uuid:Ramsey\Uuid\Lazy\LazyUuidFromString:private] => 5909c9e3-1690-4cd0-b0f0-0151e6f7996a
        )

    [published_at] => 17252753310188
    // [body]  =>... more fields of enqueueu table
)

When I change line L69 to
'id' => \Enqueue\Util\UUID::generate(),  saving to database works.
Array
(
    [id] => 6f9cfd8d-4f3a-4675-9f95-a2099de60457
    [published_at] => 17252757497569
    //[body] => ... 
)

There seems to be an issue to convert the Object to an Uuid string somewhere later or it is only SQL Server related.
Does anyone know of a solution for this problem?

Please write a meaningful title, as per [ask]; you have 3 tags in there as tags, resulting in your title basically being "UUID error", which isn't a permitted title as it's not descriptive.
